# Long running Azure Webjob - Keeps stopping

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have been working with Azure webjobs for a while now but am still struggling to figure out why some extremely long running web job fails..

I have webjob which is built using the Azure SDK and get's triggered from a queue message coming in. This web job pulls a blob of XML from Azure Blob storage which contains information about 110000 items, it then loops through these and using REST WebApi2 endpoints  makes various HttpClient requests to create the various entities in both our table storage and DocumentDB... the process is slooooow something I'm working on, but it runs for days... which is fine as there is no urgency, apart from it keeps randomly just stopping, sometimes after two days... the last time the only message was "Thread was being aborted". I making regular logging out and http calls so it's not like the job is sat there doing nothing...
**UPDATE:**

I should also state I have upgraded the whole app service plan to S1 and set the web app hosting the web job to Always On...

I have also looked at "WEBJOBS_RESTART_TIME" but this is not relevant as it's about restarting after stopping, something I assumed a continuous job with no error shouldn't do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had many problems with long-running web jobs and ended up buying paid support because the jobs would fail so often and we just couldn't figure out why.  This has been going on for 2+ months and there is still no resolution.  They did recommend using the local_cache setting which for a while stopped the reboots but eventually, the reboots started again.

We had moved these off of a vm where they had run flawlessly for years.  In my opinion, web jobs just aren't suitable for long running jobs and you should move to a vm.  We have a number of short running jobs and they do just fine but for anything long running, I think that web jobs are not ready for prime time. We have spent a lot of time with support on these issues to no avail and frankly, we feel that we're just wasting our time at this point.  Save yourself the pain and go to a vm and revisit this in 6 months.

Comment: When you have a production system that fails multiple times per day and you're paying for support that can't resolve the issue, waiting for news from a conference may not be the best strategy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's always interesting and strangely reassuring to know I'm not the only one struggling with this. Microsoft guidelines are that web jobs should have the ability to pick up where we left off, I guess when you are potentially being juggled between resources etc it's not surprising. Once I added this logic into my jobs then the fact it restarted didn't actually matter. 

I guess when you look at it like that, then yeah, your jobs probably should be a little bit more defensively programmed to allow for this.

Comment: A few items I've learned since I posted the above:  1)  they actually don't move around your Webapp/Webjob that much and so a job failure is rarely a sign of such activity.  This was told to me by a support tech.  This leads me to believe that the "pick up where it left off" strategy is Microsoft's way of dealing with the underlying problem 2)  Don't bother buying support if you're not a premiere client because you really don't get much other than if your question is a "how do I" type thing.  We have moved everything back to a VM and it's been rock solid so we know it's not our code.....

Comment: We actually moved over to AWS.  While they don't have Webjobs/apps there, the support is really good and they've helped us with some minor issues we had.  We never were able to get the jobs to stop failing in Azure and support would just tell us "we're working on it" but nothing ever happened.  Perhaps things have improved such that long running jobs are stable but we would not consider going back to Azure at this time.

Answer (score 5):

There is one thing with long running webjobs that I found out. For the thread to continue working for really long periods of time you either have to:

- Write to the output with Console.Write every now and then
- Add an App Setting called **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** ([source](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs#configuration-settings)) which defines to amount of time that the environment will wait for an Idle webjob (no Console output) before shutting it down.

I'd do both, add the Console.Write like a "heartbeat" and add the App Setting.

Comment: Thanks, but I am writing Trace.TraceInformation all over the place, like every second so I can't see that Azure thinks it's Idle... but will add that setting... I tend to not use Console.Write in a webjob, as if you use trace it rights it straight to blob storage for you!!

Comment: I understand, the problem is that the process that "watches" over the Webjob idling is checking the "output", which in this case, is the Console.

Comment: Genius!!! So they put a nice easy way of logging out messages and then monitor a different one!!! Got to love the joined up thinking, but thanks a million for the heads up.... will see how it goes!!!

Comment: Hahaha I'm just pointing to things I've learned with experience :) Try with the App Setting first and see if it solves your Timeout issues, if all else fails, you can always make a Console.Write heartbeat :)